# How Nodejs insert a string to the n-th line of file easily?

Tags: node.js, file-io

I googled around and checked a few npm (e.g. Lazy), but still couldn't find a good pattern to insert a string to n-th number of line of a file.

Being a newbie to Nodejs, I suppose this could be done easily as in other languages, e.g. PHP / Ruby.

Thanks for your solution in advance.

Comment: This is a good way to start to learn Nodejs.  What did you try?

Comment: Thanks @WiredPrairie, I am trying to insert some new data to many CSV files (about thousands lines each). I tried to avoid managing the data with mongodb as importing the data in db takes a long time and unnecessary for my project.

Comment: The question I had was about what code you've tried to write on your own to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is:

1. Open a file in read mode

`var fileData = fs.createReadStream('filename.extension');'

1. Read line-by-line and track a counter
2. Check this counter with your desired `n-th` line number
3. If matched: append the line `fileData.write("this is a message");` by opening file in append mode and traversing to the counter.
   If didn't match: print "No such position found. Error!"
   I'd probably use one of 'given input stream, notify me on each line' modules, for example node-lazy or byline:

   var fs = require('fs'),
       byline = require('byline');

   var stream = byline(fs.createReadStream('sample.txt'));
   stream.on('line', function(line) { 
       // do stuff with line
   });
   stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./output');

If your file is small, you can simply read all of the file synchronously and split the result string like this:

`require('fs').readFileSync('abc.txt').toString().split('\n').forEach(function (line) { line; })[1]`

Another way:

**[Line-by-line npm](https://npmjs.org/package/line-by-line)**

```
var LineByLineReader = require('line-by-line'),
var lr = new LineByLineReader('big_file.txt');

lr.on('error', function (err) {
    // 'err' contains error object
});

lr.on('line', function (line) {
    // pause emitting of lines...
    lr.pause();

    // ...do your asynchronous line processing..
    setTimeout(function () {

        // ...and continue emitting lines.
        lr.resume();
    }, 100);
});

lr.on('end', function () {
    // All lines are read, file is closed now.
});
```

**Your node-lazy way:**

```
var     lazy    = require("lazy"),
        fs  = require("fs");
var matched_line_number = 10;// let say 10, can be any

 new lazy(fs.createReadStream('./MyVeryBigFile.extension'))
     .lines
     .forEach(function(line){
         console.log(line.toString());
         ctr++;
     }
 );
```

**Another way could be:**

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    async = require('async'),
    carrier = require('carrier');

async.parallel({
    input: fs.openFile.bind(null, './input.txt', 'r'),
    output: fs.openFile.bind(null, './output.txt', 'a')
}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("An error occured: " + err);
        return;
    }

    carrier.carry(result.input)
        .on('line', result.output.write)
        .on('end', function () {
            result.output.end();
            console.log("Done");
        });
});
```

Open you file in read mode and line-by-line check for the desired line and simultaneously write it to another file with manipulating your lines.

Comment: Thanks @varun-malhotra for the very detailed solutions. Can you elaborate how to traverse the buffer to the desired n-th line number (without using any extensions)?